# get values from json format object

Tags: c#, javascript

In my asp.Net application (MVC 3) in a View I am working with some jquery control. I got json

```
 {  
        "text":"Books",  
        "state":"open",  
        "attributes":{  
            "url":"/demo/book/abc",  
            "price":100  
        }
```

how can I get values of attrubutes?

Comment: try `data.attributes.url`, where data is your json object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
var json =  {   
    "text":"Books",   
    "state":"open",   
    "attributes":{   
        "url":"/demo/book/abc",   
        "price":100   
    }
```

json.attributes.url

for example.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work, elemet has attribute, has key url with value but this is not working

Comment: I have just tried it and it seemed fine, from my debugger,  json.attributes.url "/demo/book/abc" String.  If you want to post up a bit more code to give some context, please do.

Answer (score 1):

if you take

```
var data = {  
        "text":"Books",  
        "state":"open",  
        "attributes":{  
            "url":"/demo/book/abc",  
            "price":100  
        }
```

If the properties of attributes DONT change you can use `data.attributes.url` as @furqan said.
But if your properties CAN change you can just iterate through the properties like

```
    for(x in data.attrubutes)
    {
    //do some specific code for x which will be the NAME of the attribute.
//by calling data.attributes[x] for the value.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do `objectName[attributename]`   or `objectName.attributename`

for example

```
var test =  {  
        "text":"Books",  
        "state":"open",  
        "attributes":{  
            "url":"/demo/book/abc",  
            "price":100  
        }  

test.text
```

Will return the value